# Where to find documentation for the .get function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, knockout.js

Im not sure if this is even a knockout, jquery or javascript function but someone in this site gave me a code to fix an issue I had. He used a .GET method that I never seen before, heres an example of the code.

For the full code: http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/

```
// list filter & automatic loading
self.filter = ko.observable("");
self.orderby = ko.observable("");
self.params = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJS({
        $filter: self.filter,
        $orderby: self.orderby
    });
}).extend({
    rateLimit: 100
});
self.params.subscribe(self.load, self);

IncidentList.prototype.load = function(params) {
    var self = this;
    return $.get(Incident.BASE_URL, params).then(function(data) {
        if (data.d.results) {       
            self.incidents(data.d.results.map(function(item) {
                return new Incident(item);
            }));
        } else {
            console.log("no results received from server");
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("error", arguments);
    });
};
```

Now this codes gets the data from the server however returns it in XML when I was expecting JSON. So it's returning me errors because data.d.results dosent exist. I am more familiar with the Knockout $.getJSON or the .ajax method where I can add the headers manually so it can return me the JSON data I am used to.

What would you guys recomend, scrapping the functions and just use $.getJSON/AJAX or is there a way to include headers with a .get?

Answer (score 1):

That is a jquery .get(), not knockout. How about using the dataType parameter for specifying that you want JSON? Or the dataType property in the settings parameter?

[Jquery .get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)